# Having a problem understanding the execution of I/O in Von Neumann model

Tags: computer-architecture

I might have gone too deep in my search after the answer which might be much easier than what I figured.

Essentially I wanted to figure out how I/O are executed in a Von Neumann machine, but more I read, the more confused I became.

What they are saying in "Introduction to computing systems" (Patt and Patel) and other websites covering this is that I/O devices in the VN machine has an I/O controller which works as a liaison between the I/O device(s) and the CPU which will interrupt the CPU once the I/O operation is finished. 
(1. it receives the write/read request, 2. notifies the cpu and let it go back to doing whatever task it was doing, 3. interrupts it once the I/O operation is finished).

1. So this is some kind of Interrupt-driven I/O, but is that enough to explain how I/O are executed in VN machine?
2. How does a program communicate with an I/O device?
3. How will you explain the data transfer between memory and I/O devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not wrong in stating that you went too deep in your search.

To counter these confusions, you might want to study how instructions are executed electronically in a computer.

The one thing worth remembering is: In a computer *everything* is controlled by the CPU. That includes the IO devices, their interfaces, the instructions put forth by them and the ones relegated to them.

Typically, what happens is that a program or a facility in your machine generates interrupts. Generally, the interrupt itself is an instruction to the CPU coming from the memory, loaded in the memory by the CPU itself at a prior time. When the CPU executes the interrupt, it checks the status of I/O device (like a key press), registers it and manipulates it as per instructions that follow. When modern computers turn on, BIOS - Basic Input Output System, that is - is used for generating interrupts and is used as an interface/liaison between the CPU and I/O devices. BIOS itself is a program (set of instructions) that resides on ROM and is read by the CPU at time zero. After the boot up is complete and OS is loaded to the memory, this facility is provided by the Operating System.

> How does a program communicate with an I/O device?

That depends upon the level of abstraction you are working on. If you want to see the program as a single and lone set of instructions to the CPU then the I/O interrupts are a part of the program. They are executed and tell the processor which device is to be contacted and in what manner. A little knowledge of assembly would be helpful for clarification in this context. But a small example of instructions to CPU is as follows:

```
1. Load integer 8 in Register 1.  //Instruction 'Load', Data '8'
2. Check keyboard for key press.  //An interrupt to Keyboard
3. Store key press value in Register 2.
4. Add contents of Register 1 and Register 2 in Register 3.
5. Pass contents of Register 3 to Display. //An output interrupt.
```

In the case of an operating system like Windows, the interrupts are a part of operating system program and are used to call the CPU's attention not only to I/O devices, but also to other programs in the memory. The IO interrupts here are in driver domain present in the memory as an interface. The user applications or the other programs in memory make calls to the operating system to make these interrupts, they can not directly make interrupts. Following is an example of a simple program in MSIL assembly.

```
.maxstack 2    
.entrypoint   //begins here.
ldc.i4 8      //load integer 8 to stack.
ldc.i4 9      //load integer 9 to stack too.
add           //Add last two integers.
call void [mscorlib]System.Console.WriteLine(int32)  //A call to windows to 
              //display the answer in console. Windows does the rest.
```

> How will you explain the data transfer between memory and I/O devices?

An instruction by a program to check the status of IO device. An instruction to get the data from the device and store it into a register. An instruction to store the value of that register into a memory location at a certain address in RAM. That location can be read by the program when required.

Answer (score 2):

Many, rather different, machines are lumped under "von Neuman". The critical pieces are that there is a read/write memory (RAM), which contains instructions and data. Instructions are executed by a processor (CPU) while reading/writing data to memory. I believe the original model did not consider I/O, other than some rudimentary method of setting memory contents by hand (toggling switches) and reading out results the same way.

Modern computers are not von Neuman, far from it. There are several processors (just lower-end cellphones have a single core anymore), and futhermore many of the "I/O devices" are handled by DMA (Direct Memory Access, the device takes instructions to read/write to a memory area without CPU intervention). Modern, high-performance devices are quite capable computers on their own. Handling part of the network stack is integrated into higher-end network cards; WiFi requires a very complex set of operations, again most of those are done by the card, not the CPU. Graphics cards are built around fast vector processors (the same operation is executed on an array of data in parallel), which are programmed in their own language, with the CPU mostly shuffling data into/out of the card,